# Android webview 'fixed positioning' alternative

Tags: android, webview, css-position

I use a `WebView` to show a table. The table is too big for the screen so the user must scroll through the page. I want to show a fixed header which is always visible. Since the `position:fixed` is not working on most versions of the `WebView`, I implemented an alternative using the `onScroll` event and manually positioning the header.
The problem with this is that the `onScroll` event is only fired when the scrolling is finished. This means that if you scroll up the header will be scrolled too from top to bottom until you stop scrolling and then the event is fired and it is repositioned.
Anyone a better solution how to show this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My final solution is to use two webviews, one on top of the other. The upper one shows the header, the lower one the content. To solve horizontal scrolling, a background thread synchronizes the `scrollX`-position of the header with this of the content webview. This thread runs as long as the user is touching the content webview or the last webview's `scrollX`-position is different than the previous one. The latter is necessary because a user can swipe the content and then lift its finger. This works very well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes I found something for fixed elements positioning in webview, as there is a meta tag with viewport if you are saying user-scalable is yes then you have to modify with no. I have tried all around tips but nothing did change. I have gone with the fix that view port meta tag. You can change the meta tag This works fine. Thanks

Comment: This worked very well for me, I wanted to lock down the view to avoid horizontal scrolling as well as have a fixed toolbar at the top of my view. Achieved this with the following meta tag: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />

Comment: I tried this header `<meta name='viewport' content='target-densitydpi=240, width=device-width, user-scalable=no'/>` but it doesn't work with the webpage I'm showing. The header still isn't fixed but scrolls until scrolling is done. Then it is repositioned at the top of the page.